# Getting this exception in MongoDB Failed to completely discover replica set appdbRS

Tags: replication, mongodb, clustering

There is a problem with the address: address=om-3- proud-toad.mdbtraining.net:
there is no space after '3-' CAN ANYONE TELL WHERE CAN I CHANGE THE ADDRESS?

```
2024-01-05T13:13:58.938+0000 [DiagnosticsSvc-0] INFO  com.xgen.svc.core.svc.DiagnosticsSvc [DiagnosticsSvc.java:checkAndSetCpuLoadAvg:69] - System 5min load average observed of 0.0 with 4.0 available CPU cores on this machine.
2024-01-05T13:14:58.937+0000 [DiagnosticsSvc-0] INFO  com.xgen.svc.core.svc.DiagnosticsSvc [DiagnosticsSvc.java:checkAndSetGc:113] - Garbage collector activity. 0.0% of last 60000ms was spent in ParNew GC activity.
2024-01-05T13:14:58.938+0000 [DiagnosticsSvc-0] INFO  com.xgen.svc.core.svc.DiagnosticsSvc [DiagnosticsSvc.java:checkAndSetGc:113] - Garbage collector activity. 0.0% of last 60000ms was spent in ConcurrentMarkSweep GC activity.
2024-01-05T13:14:58.938+0000 [DiagnosticsSvc-0] INFO  com.xgen.svc.core.svc.DiagnosticsSvc [DiagnosticsSvc.java:checkAndSetCpuLoadAvg:69] - System 5min load average observed of 0.0 with 4.0 available CPU cores on this machine.
2024-01-05T13:15:42.452+0000 [DeploymentDiscoverySvcDeploymentRefresher-0] INFO  com.xgen.svc.mms.svc.admin.DeploymentDiscoverySvc [DeploymentDiscoverySvc.java:discoverStandalone:341] - Failed to completely discover process:**om-3- proud-toad.mdbtraining**.net:27017 message:Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=om-3- proud-toad.mdbtraining.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: om-3- proud-toad.mdbtraining.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: om-3- proud-toad.mdbtraining.net}}]
2024-01-05T13:15:58.937+0000 [DiagnosticsSvc-0] INFO  com.xgen.svc.core.svc.DiagnosticsSvc [DiagnosticsSvc.java:checkAndSetGc:113] - Garbage collector activity. 0.0% of last 60000ms was spent in ParNew GC activity.
2024-01-05T13:15:58.938+0000 [DiagnosticsSvc-0] INFO  com.xgen.svc.core.svc.DiagnosticsSvc [DiagnosticsSvc.java:checkAndSetGc:113] - Garbage collector activity. 0.0% of last 60000ms was spent in ConcurrentMarkSweep GC activity.
2024-01-05T13:15:58.938+0000 [DiagnosticsSvc-0] INFO  com.xgen.svc.core.svc.DiagnosticsSvc [DiagnosticsSvc.java:checkAndSetCpuLoadAvg:69] - System 5min load average observed of 0.0 with 4.0 available CPU cores on this machine.
2024-01-05T13:16:12.454+0000 [DeploymentDiscoverySvcDeploymentRefresher-0] INFO  com.xgen.svc.mms.svc.admin.DeploymentDiscoverySvc [DeploymentDiscoverySvc.java:discoverReplicaSet:421] - Failed to completely discover replica set appdbRS: message:Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=om-3- proud-toad.mdbtraining.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: **om-3- proud-toad.mdbtraining.net**}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: **om-3- proud-toad.mdbtraining.net**}}]
2024-01-05T13:16:12.454+0000 [DeploymentDiscoverySvcDeploymentRefresher-0] INFO  com.xgen.svc.mms.svc.admin.DeploymentDiscoverySvc [DeploymentDiscoverySvc.java:discoverReplicaSet:428] - Completed discovery for replica set appdbRS
2024-01-05T13:16:58.937+0000 [DiagnosticsSvc-0] INFO  com.xgen.svc.core.svc.DiagnosticsSvc [DiagnosticsSvc.java:checkAndSetGc:113] - Garbage collector activity. 0.0% of last 60000ms was spent in ParNew GC activity.
2024-01-05T13:16:58.938+0000 [DiagnosticsSvc-0] INFO  com.xgen.svc.core.svc.DiagnosticsSvc [DiagnosticsSvc.java:checkAndSetGc:113] - Garbage collector activity. 0.0% of last 60000ms was spent in ConcurrentMarkSweep GC activity.
2024-01-05T13:16:58.938+0000 [DiagnosticsSvc-0] INFO  com.xgen.svc.core.svc.DiagnosticsSvc [DiagnosticsSvc.java:checkAndSetCpuLoadAvg:69] - System 5min load average observed of 0.0 with 4.0 available CPU cores on this machine.
```

Comment: Remove the member from Replica Set and add it again with correct name.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, am new to this; How to remove it from the replica set?

Comment: This isnt part of a replicaset
`[ec2-user@om-3-proud-toad ~]$ mongo --quiet --eval "rs.status()"
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "no replset config has been received",
        "code" : 94,
        "codeName" : "NotYetInitialized"
}`

Comment: Did you initiate the Replica Set?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, yes

Comment: Ok, but this does not match with `"codeName" : "NotYetInitialized"- Perhaps you deleted the `local` database or something else

Comment: Check with `rs.conf()` if the host is wrong there, `rs.reconfig()` may help